# Access Denied for password reset page

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to redirect user to edit profile page after accessing the password reset link, code looks like

```
function mymodule_reset_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Drupal's default behavior is to show the user a log-in form before
  // their user profile.  We replace this item to skip the uneccesary step.
  $items['user/reset/%/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Account settings',
    'access callback' => 'simple_pass_reset_pass_reset_access',
    'access arguments' => array(2, 3, 4),
    'page callback' => 'test',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3, 4),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

}

function test($uid, $timestamp, $hashed_pass, $option = NULL) {
  global $user;
  // Show the user edit form instead of silly one-time login form.
  $account = user_load($uid);
  $user = $account;
  $token = drupal_random_key();
  $_SESSION['pass_reset_' . $user->uid] = $token;
  drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/edit', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
 }
```

while test() is callback for menu 'user/reset/%/%/%'.

The issue is when the user access the link for first time user gets "Access Denied" for second time user successfully redirects to edit profile page with password reset option. I think issue must be in the way the token is generated as it is the only thing which changes, but have no clue on how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal has an option to just login using the user reset link. When you add */login* after the reset link the user is logged in directly and redirected to their their profile page.

Comment: thanks @h3rj4n was not aware of altering the link that way, really quick and cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

After new information, what I have done:

1. installed simple_pass_reset module and enabled it.
2. putted your code in my custom module.
3. generated reset link for the user, something like this  user/reset/1/1421238775/nyUMDVFKAizcXsjVFNsZQcUdh6Y3CG9TdbEzFaZnyJQ/login
4. this link redirected me to user/1/edit?pass-reset-token=Nock8yzQbSa8Sp8EC2JwtjPzDwv3vwPiGAyPyp0l_os

it works because drupal have default behavior when we add /login to reset link, it won't redirect without it

---

After some investigation

it will work like this without /login if:
- disable simple pass reset module
- change code

```
function adyax_ajax_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Drupal's default behavior is to show the user a log-in form before
  // their user profile.  We replace this item to skip the uneccesary step.
  $items['user/reset/%/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Account settings',
    'page callback' => 'test',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3, 4),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}

function test($uid, $timestamp, $hashed_pass, $option = NULL) {
  global $user;
  // Show the user edit form instead of silly one-time login form.
  $account = user_load($uid);
  $user = $account;
  user_login_finalize();
  $token = drupal_random_key();
  $_SESSION['pass_reset_' . $user->uid] = $token;
  drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/edit', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
}
```

Comment: not working for me.

Comment: Can you provide more information. For example: hook_menu where you create  'user/reset/%/%/%' item

Comment: I altered the menu path as per the requirement, updated the question

Comment: check h3rj4n comment, he is right

Comment: thanks @smile for detailed answer, can't disable simple_pass_reset, as there is lot more this module is doing for me :), but I am really confused what was causing the issue for access denied, surprisingly the code is working without a change, which is even of bigger concern to me, I will test your /login way, next time I will see the issue. Thanks again